# Filled 3D numpy mask

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, geometry

I have a binary (0-1) 3D numpy array, which I plan to use for masking a 3D image. The mask at the moment consists in the area of a cylinder. The two centres of the faces are two arbitrary points, and the axis is not parallel to x, y or z.
How can I fill the cylinder with a pure numpy solution?

Comment: Do you need to mark surface cells (area mentioned) or fill the volume? How large is cylinder relative to all array?

Comment: @MBo I need to fill the cylinder in order to mask all its volume. The cylinder is about 1/100 of all array

Comment: Do you already have the coordinates (or the mask) of the surface of the cylinder or do you have the analytical description (orientation, height, radius, position of the center)?

Comment: Are you going to fill many different cylinders? I ask because it is much simpler to traverse all cells an mark those inside than make cylinder voxelization.

Comment: @MBo I already have the mask of the surface and, yes, given two points I should be able to build various cylinders. The latter is not a problem, though, because I have the algorithm to do it.

Comment: Given that a cylinder is a convex shape, you could loop into 2 out of the 3 dimensions and reduce the problem to 1D. There it is easy to write it in a vectorized way because all you have to do is fill with `1`s between the min and max indexes where you found `1`s already (the surface). But perhaps there are faster solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: `pymrt.geometry` has been removed in favor of [`raster_geometry`](https://pypi.org/project/raster-geometry/).

---

Given that a cylinder is a convex shape, it is possible to loop through all but 1 dimension and reduce the problem to 1D. There (in 1D), it is easy to write an efficient way of filling the gaps, because all is need is, essentially, to find where the boundaries are (which can be done with `numpy.where()`) and then fill everything from the minimum and the maximum coordinates.

This is implemented in [`pymrt.geometry.fill_convex()`](https://bitbucket.org/norok2/pymrt/src/99383d359c4dd00c46d1d0fa8a4a9750f7f16189/pymrt/geometry.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) for N-dimensional problems (not yet available in the `pypi` version, needs to be taken from the Bitbucket repo).
Disclaimer, I am the main author of it.

Briefly, the (simplified) code (adapted to 3D) looks like:

```
def fill_convex(arr):
    for i in range(arr.shape[1]):
        for j in range(arr.shape[2]):
            mask = slice(None), slice(i, i + 1), slice(j, j + 1)
            line = arr[mask]
            k = np.where(line > 0)[0]
            if len(k):
                start, stop = np.min(k), np.max(k)
                line[start:stop] = 1
    return arr
```

To see this in action on a concrete (but 2D and not cylindrical / elliptical) example:

```
import numpy as np
import pymrt as mrt
import pymrt.geometry

# generate a convex border (although it is not elliptical)
points = ((1, 1), (0, 6), (5, 4), (4, 2))
line_points = tuple(x for x in mrt.geometry.bresenham_lines(points, True))
arr = mrt.geometry.render_at((8, 8), line_points)
print(arr.astype(int))
# [[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0]
#  [0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0]
#  [0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
#  [0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]
#  [0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

# fill everything inside the convex shape
arr = mrt.geometry.fill_convex(arr)
print(arr.astype(int)
# [[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0]
#  [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
#  [0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
#  [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
#  [0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's it

Comment: Python adepts made nice libraries for every case you can only imagine ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have surface cells marked and there si no additional information, then scan array layer by layer to get the first marked cell (or get some surface cell if they are known).

When you have marked A[z,y,x] surface cell, fill line in the last dimension (x) 1d array until new marked cell is met.

Then find neighbor marked cell in the same top-level layer (same z, close y ans x) and repeat to fill lines until whole section (ellipse or cutted ellipse) is filled, then continue with the next z layer

**Edit**
Perhaps I overcomplicate the problem, and FloodFill algo is simple solution.

Comment: Thanks! i'll check FloodFill too